# Access Java int Array in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, applet, int

I have a Java applet that has an int array. I want to copy this array over to a JavaScript array. Simply calling a Java function from JavaScript that returns this array results in null exception and accessing the array element by element from JavaScript leads to browser crashes. What is the correct way to handle this? Perhaps JSObject?

Comment: Java runs on the server-side. JS runs on the client side. Are you sure you want to support a call from the client to the server ?

Comment: @alfasin Since Java 1.1 its possible to run Java-Code on Client via Applets.

Comment: @PeterRader My bad - I didn't notice this question has an `applet` tag

Comment: @alfasin yes, often the tags are misfits (like `int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<applet code="Applet.class" name="Applet" />
<script>var f = document.Applet.foobar();</script>
```

And

```
class Applet extends java.applet.Applet {
    public void init() {}
    public int[] foobar(){
        return new int[]{1,2,3};
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, I guess that it worked now. Didn't work when I tried the same thing earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, it won't work if the Browser asks for Applet-Permission first. Usually programmers write a hello-callback-function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use netscape JSObject to interact with JavaScript from Java Applet. Have a look at the below tutorial. It might be useful for you.

[JSObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html)

Comment: Thanks, but simply calling a function that returns the int array turned out to be easier.

Comment: Yes. it's simpler indeed :)